# Read a specific range of lines from a file using c

Tags: c, linux, file, file-io

I have the following content in a file:

```
hhasfghgsafjgfhgfhjf
gashghfdgdfhgfhjasgfgfhsgfjdg
jfshafghgfgfhfsghfgffsjgfj
.
.
.
.
.
startread
hajshjsfhajfhjkashfjf
hasjgfhgHGASFHGSHF
hsafghfsaghgf
.
.
.
.
.
stopread
.
.
.
.
.
.
jsfjhfhjgfsjhfgjhsajhdsa
jhasjhsdabjhsagshaasgjasdhjk
jkdsdsahghjdashjsfahjfsd
```

I need to read the lines from the next line of `startread` till the previous line of `stopread` using a c code and store it to a string variable(of course with a `\n` for every line breaks). How can i achieve this?
I have used `fgets(line,sizeof(line),file);` but it starts reading from the beginning. I don't have the exact line number to start and stop reading since the file is written by another C code. But there are these identifiers `startread` and `stopread` to identify whereto start reading. Operating platform is linux. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: You could use `getline` (from Posix 2008 and in Gnu libc).

Comment: @James Joy: Hi did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) to detect `startread` and `stopread`. Ignore all lines read until `"startread"` is read and then store all lines until `"stopread"` is read:

```
/* Read until "startread". */
char line[1024];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) &&
       0 != strcmp(line, "startread\n"));

/* Read until "stopread", only if "startread" found. */
if (0 == strcmp(line, "startread\n"))
{
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) &&
           0 != strcmp(line, "stopread\n"))
    {
        /* Do something with 'line'. */
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I had the same idea but I still don't get how to make a condition to do as you said. I mean `which` while can be used for reading each line.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #define MAX_BUF_LEN 1000    
    int flag=0;
    while(fgets(buf, MAX_BUF_LEN, file) != NULL){
       if(strncmp(buf, "startread", strlen("startread")) == 0){
          flag=1;
       }
       else if (strncmp(buf, "stopread", strlen("stopread")) == 0){
          flag=0;
       }

       if(flag){
          strncpy(line, buf, strlen(buf));
         // strncat(line, '\n', strlen('\n'));
       }

    // that's all!
    }
    fclose(file);
```

This should works.